# Serialize Many to Many Relationship with Extra fields

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Please I'm stuck trying to get around this issue. Guess there is something I'm not getting after looking at other similar questions.

I have these models:

```
class Dish(BaseModel):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'dishes'
    name = models.CharField(_('dish'), max_length=100)
    dish_type = models.CharField(_("dish type"), max_length=100)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("price"))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} costs {self.price}"


class Order(BaseModel):

    dishes = models.ManyToManyField(Dish, through='DishOrder')
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("total discount"), blank=True)
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("total"), blank=True)
    shipping = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("shipping cost"), blank=True)
    grand_total = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("grand total"), blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(_('country code'), max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"order from {self.customer} at {self.total}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('order-details', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class DishOrder(models.Model):
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dishes')
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='dishes')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("quantity"))
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(_("discount"))
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('price'))
```

And the corresponding serializers like so:

```
class DishOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DishOrder
        fields = (
            "quantity",
            "discount",
            "price"
        )

class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = DishOrderSerializer(source='dish', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            "id",
            "country",
            "customer",
            "dishes", 
            "total", 
            "discount",
            "grand_total",
            "voucher"
        )
```

So as can be seen, I have a m2m relationship via a through table. However I can't get the serializer to work. This is the error I keep getting:

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `dishes`
>   on serializer `OrderSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
>   incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Order`
>   instance. Original exception text was: 'Order' object has no attribute
>   'dish'.

I have been looking through this for some time trying to figure out what the error is. I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `related_name='dishes'` in model you should use `dishes` as source to the manytomany objects:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = DishOrderSerializer(source='dishes', many=True)
```

or simple:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dishes = DishOrderSerializer(many=True)
```

Since `source='dishes'` redundant in case you named serializer's field `dishes` also.